# Manipulate the EFLAGS register in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, flags

I know of the assembly instructions `LAHF`, `SAHF` that can load `AH` from and store `AH` into the `FLAGS` register. But how do I do the same for the `EFLAGS` register? Are there any specific instructions too or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-5477/eoizw/index.html)

Comment: Answers go in the answer box.

Comment: ... but you should be aware that many bits of EFLAGS cannot be modified directly but only by an "IRET" instruction and only if the task register is set up propperly.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#EFLAGS_Register